# C# LINQ DateTime Null and Like

Tags: c#, sql, linq

i'm trying to execute a linq off a DataTable but having problems with Like statement, and need some assistance.

```
        var query = from results in  referenceDt.AsEnumerable()
                    where results.IsNull("ClosedTime") &&
                    **????**
                    select new
                    {
                        Cluster = results.Field<string>("FaultCode"),
                        DC = results.Field<Int32>("FaultCode"),
                        Region = results.Field<string>("FabricName")
                    };
```

Here is what my sql query looks like:

```
   SELECT FaultCode, COUNT(FaultCode) AS Count, FabricName 
        FROM RmaSummary
        WHERE ClosedTime IS null AND FaultCode LIKE '60%'
        ) GROUP BY FaultCode, FabricName 
        ORDER BY FabricName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var query = from results in  referenceDt.AsEnumerable()
                where results.Field<DateTime?>("ClosedTime") == null &&
                      results.Field<int>("FaultCode").ToString().StartsWith("60")
                select results;

 var count = results.Count();
```

Comment: I forgot to ask. I also have a COUNT in my sql statement.  How would I add a COUNT and GROUP?

Comment: Your grouping is not clear to me. It doesn't make the group by FaultCode and then count the number of groups in that group (it will always be 1)

Comment: Should I then group?  Will that return the number of times a FaultCode is in my table?

Comment: Number of different FaultCodes or number of FaultCodes which start with 60?

Comment: Count the number of FaultCodes that start with 60

Answer (score 1):

Use StartsWith() method available for strings,

```
var query = from results in  referenceDt.AsEnumerable()
            where results.IsNull("ClosedTime") &&
            results.Field<Int32>("FaultCode").ToString().StartsWith("60")
            select new
            {
                  Cluster = results.Field<string>("FaultCode"),
                  DC = results.Field<Int32>("FaultCode"),
                  Region = results.Field<string>("FabricName")
            };
```